# Fastest datastructure for filtering schema-less collections

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, collections

Lets say I have a collection

```
var data = [
  { fieldA: 5 },
  { fieldA: 142, fieldB: 'string' },
  { fieldA: 1324, fieldC: 'string' },
  { fieldB: 'string', fieldD: 111, fieldZ: 'somestring' },
  ...
];
```

Lets assume fields are not uniform across elements but I know in advance the number of unique fields, and that the collection is not dynamic.

I want to filter it with something like `_.findWhere`. This is simple enough, but what if I want to prioritize speed over ease? Is there a better data structure that will always minimize the number of elements that will be checked? Perhaps some kind of tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is something faster if your queries are of the type "give me all records with fieldX=valueY". However, it does have an overhead.

For each field, build an inverted index that lists all the record-ids ( = row positions in the original `data`) that have each value:

```
var indexForEachField = {
    fieldA: { "5": [0], "142": [1], "1324": [2]},
    ...
}
```

When someone asks for "records where fieldX=valueY", you return

```
indexForEachField["fieldX"]["valueY"]; // an array with all results
```

Lookup time is therefore constant (and requires only 2 lookups in tables), but you do need to keep your index up to date.

This is a generalization of the strategy used by search engines to look up webpages with certain terms; in that scenario, it is called an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).

---

Edit: what if you want to find all records with fieldX=valueX **and** fieldY=valueY?

You would use the following code, which requires all input arrays 
to be sorted:

```
var a = indexForEachField["fieldX"]["valueX"];
var b = indexForEachField["fieldY"]["valueY"];
var c = []; // result array: all elements in a AND in b
for (var i=0, j=0; i<a.length && j<b.length; /**/) {
    if (a[i] < b[j]) {
       i++;
    } else if (a[i] > b[j]) {
       j++;
    } else {
       c.push(a[i]);
       i++; j++;
    }
}
```

You can see that, in the worst case, the total complexity is exactly `a.length + b.length`; and, in the best case, half of that. You can use something very similar to implement OR.

Comment: Good answer. The OP said the collection is not dynamic. He could potentially compute the index only once - even precompute it and load it if it is truly static.

Comment: This answers the case for `_.where(collection, { fieldA: 5 })`. Lets say I want to find an intersection of 2 queries (same as  `_.where(collection, { fieldA: 5, fieldB: 'string' })`. In this case, a inverted index lookup would require searching both query results for intersections--which is not constant, and is actually worse than just looping through `data` (n*m I think?)

Comment: @NathanHagen - wrong; you just have to calculate the union (OR) or intersection (AND) of sets, which can be done in O(n+m), where n and m are the sizes of the sets (typically much smaller than the total document count), assuming that they are pre-ordered. It can be done even faster if you have few documents and you build bit-masks instead of arrays: you can AND and OR bit-masks directly...