# Implement a sortedMap with subsequence matching

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, treemap, sortedmap

I want to implement a sortedMap with keys and values such that the keys can be searched by providing some subsequence. For example, the map contains 3 entries:

```
abcd -> obj1
def -> obj2
abccd -> obj3
```

For query `ac`, result should be a submap containing the 1st and 3rd entries, but for query `acc`, only 3rd entry should be returned.

What kind of data structure should I use internally to efficiently return such submap? For example, the `Treemap` which stores the keys in a tree (trie) to efficiently return the submap based on the prefix?

Comment: for query `bc`, should your map return first and third entries?

Comment: Your terminology is incorrect.  "ac" is not a subsequence of "abcd" or "abccd".

Comment: For query "ca" should it return the 1st and 3rd entries?  Or not?

Comment: @sasha ... yes you are correct, bc should return 1st and 3rd entry

Comment: The simplest solution which comes in mind, is to use some kind of indexing by 1-, 2- and maybe 3-letter subsequences/permutations. When adding an entry, you generate all subsequences/permutations that could be obtained from a given key, then add this entry to all such "index buckets". When requesting, you take first subsequence, take a list of entries from a corresponding bucket and filter.

Comment: @stephen .. I apologize for my bad English, What I meant was, all the subsequence of abcd, such as a,b,c,d,ab, ac, ad, bc, bd,cd , abc, abd, acd, abcd etc, when queried, should return a submap with abcd -> obj1 as one of its entry.

Comment: @TheLostMind `da` is also 2-char permutation of `abcd`

Comment: @TheLostMind I understand, but OP clearfied that he needs to keep order of elements, so he needs to query by *subsequence*, not *permutation*. By definition, subsequence is one that is obtained from initial sequence by deleting some of its elements, keeping ordering of remaining elements.

Comment: Are the keys always lexicographically ordered strings?

Comment: @StephenC Judging to this (http://planetmath.org/subsequence), OP is absolutely right calling it *subsequence*. `ac` can be obtained from `abcd` by removing `b` and `d`.

Comment: @DTing .. no they can be for any string, eg.. Entry : good -> obj4, query = god, should return "good -> obj4" as one of its entry.

Comment: @Sasha .. The solution that you suggested is indeed a possibility but in case of long words, the space it would take increase exponentially. Example : for even a 5 letter key, the subsequence count is 32. For 6 letter key, the subsequence count is 64. So if I use the space, of 64 words just to store the one key, then the map wont scale more than a thousand entries, in a mobile envirnoment where the resources are very limited.

Comment: This is a tradeoff for quick access. And you won't keep 64 full words, just 64 `String` references pointing to the same value. Size of one entry in `HashMap` is 24 bytes.

Comment: Indexing would not require so much. E. g. for 2-letter `HashMap` index, you need `26^2 * (4 + 32)` = 24K bytes for keys, and `s^2/2*24*N` for values, where N is number of words, s = length of a word. For s = 6 it is `768 * N` bytes, not so big.

Comment: You're not right about *exponential* growth, number of subsequences of given length is defined by binominal coefficient, not exponent. For s = 10 and 2-char subsequences such number would be `s * (s - 1) / 2 = 45`

Comment: No, I mean that you should have 2 maps: main (key -> object) and index (subsequence -> key). In index map for 2-char subsequences, you'll have 26^2 keys, every entry will occupy 24 (size of `HashMap.Entry`) + 4 (2 chars) + 32 (size of `String`) bytes. And every key word needs to be stored as full string **once**, because index map would keep references to the `String` key, not the byte array itself.

Comment: @sasha.. If you restrict the 2-char subsequence, then it will be a binomial coefficient, as you pointed out. But if we want to store all the subsequence , it will be exponential as it would be the sum of binomial cofficient from 1 to lenght.

Comment: @user2436032 I think storing **all** subsequences is useless, because their number really grows fast. My main idea: by first 2 chars of a query you receive list of keys from index map, then filter all keys to match a query, then collect entries from the main map.

Comment: @Sasha, By keeping only the index map of 2 character, I wont be able to search for the subsequence query of lenght of 3 or more. eg. In the original question : On giving the query of acc, should return the 3rd entry only.

Comment: @sasha. its a good idea to store the 2 character subsequence and then filter later, I will try it . Thanks

Comment: You take result for 2-char subsequence then filter it to match full query. To reduce number of keys taken by first step, you can expand a query to all possible 2-char subsequences and use the *least frequent* one.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize what I've written in comments, I'd make it as following:

1. Create additional index `HashMap` with entries [2-char subsequence -> list of words].
2. **On addition:** generate all distinct 2-char subsequences from given word, add this word to every corresponding entry of index map.
3. **On querying:** generate all distinct 2-char subsequences from a query, among them find one which corresponds to the shortest list in index map, take this list. Filter it by full query and collect corresponding values from the main map.

If a query consists of one character, then perform full scan. I believe this would have better space/complexity than creating additional index for single chars, especially when 1-char queries are rare.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** My solution works in case of looking for substring. Read edit.

**Solution:**

Use prefix data structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

You will need to store:

```
abcd -> obj1
```

as:

```
abcd -> obj1
bcd -> obj1
cd -> obj1
d -> obj1
```

To find your result, you would then go deep enough in the trie to satisfy condition and DFS from there to find all possible solutions.

**Examples:**

```
ab -> obj1
cde -> obj1
bad -> obj2
```

We would insert next entries in our Trie:

```
ab -> obj1
b -> obj1
cde -> obj1
de -> obj1
e -> obj1
bad -> obj2
ad -> obj2
d -> obj2
```

Now imagine we look for next entries:

```
d
```

First move down for character d in Trie. After that we would DFS. We are already at obj2 and if we move for character e for at obj1. So we can get both of them with entry d.

```
cd
```

First we move for character c and then for character d. Now we DFS and only path we can find is by adding character e which leads to obj1.

```
efg
```

There is not path in Trie which satisfies out condition, therefore we get no solutions.

**EDIT:**

My solution works if we are looking for a substring of original element. To modify my solution for it to work for any non-contagious substring you would have to insert all the permutation aswell in the Trie.

Comment: what if a user queries `cd`? which path of search it would be?

Comment: That would be our third entry cd. You would move for char c and for char d. After that you would DFS all options, but there would be only one which is obj1.

Comment: So, for `abcd` key you need to store a whole trie for each `abcd`, `bcd`, `cd`, `d`, `acd`, `ac`, `abd`, `ab`, `ad`...?

Comment: Hi Riko, your solution will work perfectly for Substring , but it wont work for subsequence, for example, if some one query bd in the above map, it will not return entry : "abcd -> obj1" as there are no key with "bd" as prefix.

Comment: I see. In that case one would have to store all permutations of a string.

Comment: Not permutations.  The order is important.

Answer (score 0):

Your "characters" can be interpreted as terms in a traditional search-engine AND-query.

From this comment:

> all the subsequence of abcd, such as a,b,c,d,ab, ac, ad, bc, bd,cd ,
>   abc, abd, acd, abcd etc, when queried, should return a submap with
>   abcd -> obj1 as one of its entry.

We could interpret that, with a document with terms Aspid Beaver Cherokee Deer (ABCD), the document should be returned when searching for either of its words, or any of their combinations.

What you want to build for this is an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135542/fastest-datastructure-for-filtering-schema-less-collections/29135928#29135928) for more details. Essentially, you would build a `HashMap` or lookup table (there are not that many chars) for each "character" (=*term* in search-engine-speak), where a lookup would return all `objX` where it appears (=*document* in search-engine-speak), ideally in ascending order.

To find all objects associated with a set of characters, you would join the sets for each individual character. Since they are ordered, you can calculate set-intersection in linear time.

If querying for `ba` should *not* match an `abc` key, you can refine the lookup-table / `HashMap` to store character positions (eg.: store "b is found in Obj1 at position 0", "a is found in Obj1 at position 1", instead of discarding positions). When calculating search-intersection, you would proceed in search order and discard matches that have an incorrect relative order.

This is routine for search engines, and has been analyzed exhaustively in terms of performance.

---

Edit: Performance

If the number of distinct "terms" is low (for instance: the 26 lowercase English letters) you can speed this up by adding n-grams as terms (where, for "abc", you would add "a", "b", "c", "ab", "ac", "bc", and "abc"). The same rules would apply - with half the searches, and since overlap would be expected, Sasha's trick could be used to avoid storing indices.

Comment: The problem is that the scaling works against you if you are drawing from an alphabet of 26 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an aho-corasick with an wildcard. Aho-Corasick is the faster multiple pattern matching algorithm and with a wildcard it gives all substrings. You can try my php implementation at codeplex (https://phpahocorasick.codeplex.com). For example an unittest with wildcard for gene pattern:

```
$tree = new Ahocorasick\Ahocorasick();
$tree->add("AC");
$tree->add("GTG");
$tree->add("AACT");
echo $tree->match("ACCGAGTGCGTGGACAAACTACGATTGTGGAATGAACT","AC*GT");
$this->expectOutputString("ACCGAGT,ACCGAGTGCGT,ACCGAGTGCGTGGACAAACTACGATTGT,ACAAACTACGATTGT,ACTACGATTGT,ACGATTGT");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @author viborole
 *
 */
public class SortedMapSubsequence {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
    data.put("abcd", "obj1");
    data.put("def", "obj2");
    data.put("abccd", "obj3");
    String query="acc";
    search(query, data);
}

private static void search(String query, Map<String, String> data) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet())
    {
        String key=entry.getKey();
        char[] k=key.toCharArray();
        char[] q=query.toCharArray();
        int kpos=0;
        char[] found = new char[q.length];
        for(int i=0;i<q.length;i++){
            if(i>0){
                kpos++;
            }
            for(int j=kpos;j<k.length;j++){
                if(k[j]==q[i]){
                    kpos=j;
                    found[i]=k[j];
                    break;
                } 
            }
        }
        if(Arrays.equals(found,q)){
            System.out.println("found : "+ entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Vini, The solution work correctly, but it is basically a brute force method (You are checking each entry key in the set to determine whether query is a subsequence of key or not). It would be better, if we could store the keys in such a fashion(in some kind of tree) that query could be searched in less than O(n) time.